# React Native Stack Navigation With Class Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am currently building a react native app and am using a stack navigator to navigate between the screens in my app. In my App.js, I am currently storing the screens in this format:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="screen1">
          <Stack.Screen name="screen1" component={Screen1}></Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen name="screen2" component={Screen2}></Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

After the user is in screen 1, I want to be able to navigate to screen 2 on the press of a button. I read through the documentation and I only saw examples on how to do this with functional components, for example:

```
function Screen1({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('screen2')} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

But how can I do this with a class component:

```
class Screen1 extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
               // This does not work because I do not know how to pass in the navigation object
               <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('screen2')} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Where do I pass in the `{ navigation }` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You dont have to pass navigation, its passed as a prop.

You can access it like below

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('nextScreen')
```

Comment: You have an error, it should be like this: `this.props.navigation.navigate('nextScreen')`